# How to customize default border color of select after click action

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created basic select dropdown using mui.
on clicking I need to change the default color to some other color eg. grey.
default color given by mui is 'blue'.

```
<Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
          <FormControl>
            <Select
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={age}
              onChange={handleChange}
              sx={{
                minWidth: "300px",
                height: "30px",
                "& .MuiSelect-select": {
                  padding: "0.2rem"
                },
                "& .Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { // on clicking I am changing the borderColor to 'grey', but this is not taking effect
                  borderColor: "#404040"
                }
              }}
```

so, on clicking how can see border color around  of my choice?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-basic-select-4rdq61)

[image]

Comment: Add this `.MuiBox-root fieldset { border-color: red !important; }` in your CSS file and import that CSS file into App.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
sx={{
    minWidth: "300px",
    height: "30px",
    "& .MuiSelect-select": {
      padding: "0.2rem"
    },
    ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#404040 !important"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved I hope it might helpful to you thank you for the consideration.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const StyledSelect = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
"& .MuiInputBase-input": {
backgroundColor: "lightGrey",
border: "2px solid grey",
fontSize: 16,
padding: "10px 26px 10px 12px",
minWidth: "300px",
height: "30px",
"&:focus": {
borderColor: "grey"
}
}
}));

export default function BasicSelect() {
const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

const handleChange = (event) => {
setAge(event.target.value);
};

return (
<Box>
<FormControl>
<Select
id="demo-simple-select"
value={age}
onChange={handleChange}
input={<StyledSelect />}
 >
<MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
</FormControl>
</Box>
);
}
```